# deserialize xml polymorphic list with jackson

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I have problem deserializing following xml:

```
<root>
  <apples>
    <apple>
      <id>1</id>
      <weight>0.6</id>
    </apple>
    <apple>
      <id>2</id>
      <weight>0.7</id>
    </apple>
  </apples>
</root>
```

to java:

```
public class Root {
  private List<Fruits> fruits;
}
```

In above xml source other variants may be eg oranges/orange etc. also since this is propertary xml I cannot change it's schema. By default I am using `@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)` and `@JsonSubTypes({/*fruits subtypes listed*/})`. After few unsuccessful attempts I am not sure what is the proper mapping/configuration to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, `Jackson` is a `JSON` parser, not `XML`.

There are extensions for `Jackson` that allow for `XML` conversion. See http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonExtensionXmlDataBinding for more info there. But it seems as though a pure XML parser may be better for this case.

Perhaps the `javax.xml.stream.*` packages.

i.e. http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and-stax-parser-in-java.html for more info.

Comment: I'm aware of better solutions for XML mapping. I am considering using one of them. However I am writing integration for several rest services (using spring RestTemplate) - most of them uses json and now this is just second case the requirement to consume rest is XML (and without schema/DTD). So before I decide to use another solution I would try to solve this even using dedicated Deserializer.

Comment: OK. I suspect it's going to be more complex to try to use `Jackson` for `XML`, but the `XmlDataBinding` link I added above may be worth a try if you want to continue with `Jackson`. I would just add that since it's not supported out of the box, going with something like the `XmlDataBinding` is essentially another solution as well.